# Grails Generating a zip file for the user to download

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, controller, grails-orm

I am a **newbie** to **grails** currently working on a web-app project that works with users uploading pictures. Users can create a "hunt" with a list of prompts. Each "prompt" is the objective for participants (eg: upload pictures of your favorite candy.)  Basically the web-app is a "scavenger hunt" tool for Photographers to socially share their work.

Right now, I am having trouble trying write a function in my user controller to generate a zip file with all of the pictures that the user has uploaded. This is what my controller function looks like at the moment. 
I used this example I found to start.
[Generating a zip file.](http://thegrailstrail.blogspot.com/2012/07/generating-zip-files-from-multiple.html)

```
def downloadAlbum(){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(baos)

    //Instance of a user domain class
    def userInstance = User.findByLogin(auth.user())

    //pictures are uploaded to a prompt and stored as a photoInstance
    //this line of code gets the actual file stored as byte[]
        photoInstance.myFile = image.getBytes()

    //select all photos that belong to the user and store them into a list
    def photoInstanceList = userInstance ? Photo.findAllByMyUser(userInstance) : []


    //Mapping
    [userInstance: userInstance, photoInstanceList: photoInstanceList]      

      photoInstanceList.each {photo ->
        if (photoInstance.myFile != "") {
          File file = new File(photoInstance.myFile)
          zipFile.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(Photo.title+".jpeg"))
          file.withInputStream { i ->

            zipFile << i

          }
          zipFile.closeEntry()
         }
        }
        zipFile.finish()
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${login}.zip\"")
        response.contentType = "application/zip"
        response.outputStream << baos.toByteArray()
        response.outputStream.flush()   

}
```

I then use this code in the User view to generate a link that calls the function in the user controller. Am I close? Is there some missing piece in my code?

By the way, This is the first question I have ever written on Stack Overflow. I appreciate the time that you have taken to read this entry. If anything is not clear enough, please where I can improve this question. I am using grails 2.1.1

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: A stacktrace will be of great help to debug.

Comment: and what is it that happens when you use this code? No zip file? Incorrect or incomplete zip file? errors? Please update your post to tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the above code has been copied as is here, shouldn't we be using `photo.title` instead of `Photo.title` in the below line

`zipFile.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(Photo.title+".jpeg"))`